# How can I initialize a static data member of a class template with type traits?

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization, type-traits

I tried to use something like this but the initialization seems not to work. When I remove the type trait, then it works as expected.

```
template<typename _T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<_T>::value>>
struct Foo
{
    static int bar;
};

template<typename _T>
int Foo<_T>::bar = 0;
```

How to properly initialize such a static variable?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but identifiers with leading underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the compiler/library implementation. [[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you used `std::enable_if` not quite properly.

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, false> //Partial specialization
{
  // if T is not integral, Foo becomes empty class
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, true> //Partial specialization
{
    static int bar;
};
```

And then:

```
template<typename T>
int Foo<T, true>::bar = 0;
```

I changed `_T` to `T`, because name defined as `_X`, `__X` or `__x` are reserved for internal implementation.

Comment: Is it then a better way to use a static_assert inside the class to say one should only use the template with integral types?

Comment: No, `static_assert` is preferred if you want to check if some required property of a particular type is met. For example: you may want user to supply integer type, that is at least 32 bit wide - `std::enable_if` can be used to check if `T` is integral **at all** and then `static_assert` can be used to check whether `sizeof(T) >= 4`. Note, that even `std` library implementation uses `enable_if` extensively for things like "is integer".

Comment: @satanik Jjust place a `static_assert` inside the class. E.g. `class Foo { static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "..."); ... };`